# GWT Reflection loading Form

Tags: forms, reflection, lazy-loading, gxt

I have a circumstance where I have to create a lot of forms for an application, the forms are all located in the same package. They are named like: A11111.java, A11112.java, etc.

When the user clicks in the NavigationPane, I wish to load the form into a TabItem and display the form. The issue is I need to dynamically generate the name of the form by appending the form name to the location, such as String formName = "com.foo.appName.client.forms" + e.getData("formCode"); something like that, where e is the event of the user click.

I have looked at several Reflection methods, but you cannot pass a derived string to them. How best to do this? Several posts mention using generators, but I get lost trying to sort their logic, and none have to do with displaying forms.

Note, I am not passing any variables to the forms, or calling any methods in the form java files, also the forms are created using uibinding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're aiming at lazy-loading classes via the class-loader, like you would when using [the command design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command/java/2#), note that it can't be done within a GWT application, as [the frameworks JRE emulation only provides a subset of types and/or methods available in the JRE](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation), so most of the reflection API - like `forName()` - will not be available.

rather than lazy-loading classes, think in terms of lazy-rendering widgets to the DOM. this can be achieved by instantiating all your form classes on module load, but only render upon tab-switching. place all your render-related functionality inside `onRender()` callbacks and you're good to go:

```java
public class FormItem extends TabItem {

    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);

        // render related functionality
    }
}
```